# Can't install Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: software-installation, cisco

I am new to ubuntu and trying to install Cisco Packet Tracer (downloaded it from netacad.com 7.3.1 version). When I installed it, I got a .deb file and extracted it with GDebi package installer. After I successfully extracted it, but now I can't find the Packet Tracer app to start using it. I tried to install with the default installer "Software installer" but it gave me an error "exit status 1". Please help me with this!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have to extract anything. You should just be able to install it as is. ``sudo apt install <filename>.deb``

Comment: omg i just had to type 'packettracer' on my terminal. Thanks anyway!